# Struggling with MySQL NOT EXISTS

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to query our database to pull out customer data. The crucial parts are:

Pull out all customers/orders that haven't bought **product_a**.

This will list out customers/ orders who have purchased, **product_b, product_c and product_d.**

But it needs to make sure that the customer hasn't EVER purchased **product_a**. I need them excluded.

Is this the right way to go about the NOT EXISTS? I still feel like it's including some records that bought product_a.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    orders
JOIN customers AS cus ON orders.CustomerNumber = cus.CustomerNumber
WHERE
    product != 'product_a'
OR (
    HomeTelephone = ''
    AND MobileTelephone != ''
)
AND NOT EXISTS  (
    SELECT
        OrderNumber
    FROM
        orders AS o
    JOIN customers AS c ON o.CustomerNumber = c.CustomerNumber
    WHERE
        c.EmailAddress = cus.EmailAddress
    AND Product = 'product_a'
    AND completed = 1
)
ORDER BY
    orderdate
```

Without the NOT EXISTS statement, a customer record could be included even if they have bought product_a separately right?

Comment: Your problem is the `OR` in your `WHERE` clause.  It will include those records that have `HomeTelephone = '' AND MobileTelephone != ''`.  What is your intention with that part of the query?

Comment: In the where clause... Put parenthesis before product and after the OR parenthesis to see what the query processor is really doing.  Then analyze what you are really trying to do.   The OR may be working not where you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Not Exists is a little off and `where product != 'product_a'` is redundant.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM

    orders AS o1
    JOIN customers AS cus ON o1.CustomerNumber = cus.CustomerNumber
WHERE
    cus.HomeTelephone = ''
    AND cus.MobileTelephone != ''
    AND NOT EXISTS  (
        SELECT 
            1 
        FROM 
            orders o2
        WHERE
            o2.CustomerNumber = cus.CustomerNumber 
            AND Product = 'product_a'
            AND completed = 1
    )
ORDER BY
    o1.orderdate
```

This will give you the customers with their orders.  Based on your description though, if you were wanting just the customer information, you could exclude the join to orders in the first part of your query, and use the Not Exist to determine if that customer purchased product_a or not.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    customers cus
WHERE
    HomeTelephone = ''
    AND MobileTelephone != ''
    AND NOT EXISTS  (
        SELECT 
            1 
        FROM 
            orders o
        WHERE
            o.CustomerNumber = cus.CustomerNumber 
            AND Product = 'product_a'
            AND completed = 1
    )
```

Comment: You're first query SEEMS to be the one that's going to get this working - but the sub query is chugging away. I don't know what else I can do to optimise it. Without the sub its a couple of seconds, with it seems infinite!

Comment: does order table have an index on customernumber?  or product? or completed?

Comment: That'll be it!! Thank you! Super fast now.

Comment: Hi JamieD77 - I added a "normal" index to CustomerNumber in our orders table and the above query start to absolutely fly! But it seemed to kill a SELECT query we run via PHP on the website that simply pulls back todays orders, with a few other JOINS to other tables to pull various information out. Any ideas why? I had to remove the index to keep the online system running smoothly today....

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.* 
  FROM customers c
  LEFT
  JOIN orders o
    ON o.CustomerNumber = c.CustomerNumber 
   AND o.product = 'product_a'
 WHERE o.CustomerNumber IS NULL
```